# Class inheritance best practices in terms of properties and sql related methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

```
#region Properties
public int ID
{
    get;
    set;
}
public string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
public string MetaTitle
{
    get;
    set;
}
public string MetaDescription
{
    get;
    set;
}
public virtual int WebsiteID
{
    get;
    set;    
}
public DateTime TimeStamp
{
    get;
    set;
}
#endregion Properties

#region Methods 
public void Insert()
{
    string sqlString = "INSERT INTO Pages ([name], [value], [meta_title], [meta_description], [website_id]) " +
        "VALUES (@Name, @Image, @Description, @MetaTitle, @MetaDescription, @WebsiteID);";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection =
        new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", this.Name);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", this.Image);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", this.Description);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MetaTitle", this.MetaTitle);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MetaDescription", this.MetaDescription);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WebsiteID", this.WebsiteID);
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
            sqlConnection.Dispose();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Two questions:**

I have another class called `Section` which will derive from the class above called Page. However, `Section` will not have a WebsiteID but will have a PageID instead. They're both integers but how do I go about changing the property name is the derived class.

The second thing is, should I `override` the `Insert()` method to use another `sqlString`? If not, what is the best way of implementing such requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you think a using statement for the connection object would be appropriate?

Comment: Please only post just enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your inheritance might be a bit off. A "section" is NOT a "page", or is it?

Why not have a base class, called `Content` or something like that, with the properties:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

And have `Page` extend it adding the `WebsiteID` and Section adding the `PageID`.

But I would also recommend separating the entity model from the data access. Using something like Entity Framework or NHibernate to handle persistence for you would save you from having to write that code manually.

That way you could have a more connected model, where `Section` actually references a `Page` entity, and not handle IDs manually. Also `Page` could contain `Sections` in the same manner (like a `List<Section>`), and you'd possibly have a cleaner model.

Comment: Oh my god, after looking a bit into Entity Framework I feel like a complete idiot for writing the above for about 8 classes. Jeez. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have another class called Section which will derive from the class
above called Page. However, Section will not have a WebsiteID but will
have a PageID instead. They're both integers but how do I go about
changing the property name is the derived class.

The mistake is that your page contains section object so you don't have to derive Section from Page: Page must have a collection of section

```
class Page
{
     private Section[] sections;
     public Section[] Sections {get;set;}
}
```